# How do you tell whether you need to release an object?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ios4

Can you describe the naming convention difference between a method that returns an object it has allocated for the caller (and that the caller should release), and a method that returns an autorelease object?

If you declare a property with a retain attribute, do you need to release the property before you set it to nil?

What does the @synthesize directive do?

Comment: You should generally not ask three questions in one. The `@synthesize` question, in particular, has nothing to do with the other two. Each question should be one question, so that other users can search for their question and find only their question and not have to wade through other stuff that isn't related to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good source for memory allocation is listed below by Aaron.

Regarding `@synthesize`:

Say you have a property `P`, what you will have to do is write a getter and a setter for it. There are a few common approaches, one of which is that you retain that object when you set that property and release the old value. E.g:

```
- (void)setP:(PClass *)value
{
  [value retain];
  [_pInstanceVariable release];
  _pInstanceVariable = value;
}
```

Since this is a very common piece of code, the compiler can automate it for you, if you specify the `retain` keyword in property declaration and then do the `@synthesize` in you implementation. The compiler will generate the above mentioned code which means your code will be a lot cleaner without tedious repeating parts.

Same holds true for getters, unless you want something more complex than:

```
- (PClass *)p
{
  return _pInstanceVariable;
}
```

the `@synthesize` will do the job

Comment: The setter implementation here is technically incorrect. You always need to retain the value passed into a setter method before releasing your instance variable. If you don't, your app will crash if the object passed in is the same object that's already been stored in your variable.

Answer (score 3):

From [apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html)

> You only release or autorelease objects you own.
>   You take ownership of an object if you create it using a method whose name begins with “alloc” or “new” or contains “copy” (for example, alloc, newObject, or mutableCopy), or if you send it a retain message.
>
> You use release or autorelease to relinquish ownership of an object. autorelease just means “send a release message in the future” (to understand when this will be, see “Autorelease Pools”).

Your second two questions are related. All that @synthesize does is to generate additional methods for your implementation file. The arguments to @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* myString; define the behavior of the generated methods. For example, if you declare a property as retain, the setMyString generated method will retain its argument.

Nonatomic is important because properties, by default, are threadsafe. If you don't need thread safety, you can remove a lot of overhead in your accessor methods.

Finally, the implementation of a retain property is

```
- (void) setMyString:(NSString*)newString {
    [newString retain];
    [myString release];
    myString = newString;
}
```

So, saying self.myString = nil effectively releases myString for you. Many people advocate using self.property = nil for retained properties, as opposed to [property release], though I think it just comes down to personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

memory allocation information and naming can be found here

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocAllocInit.html

synthesize is documented here

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW17

The apple website has excellent documentation, I would recommend searching there first.